# Iterating over array shared between threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have an array which size does not change during the execution of my program. Let's say there are multiple threads which are changing the content of this array, something like

```
array[validIndex] = new Entity();
```

Is it safe to iterate through such array at any point in time? Let's say that I don't care about the objects which are "inside" the array.

Comment: While reading and writing to array is atomic, from what I remember array elements are not volatile, so one thread may not immediately (or depending on your program structure at all) see changes done by another thread. If that is an issue you can use classes like `AtomicReferenceArray` `AtomicIntegerArray` or use synchronized blocks.

Comment: If you don't care about the objects inside, why would you iterate through the array at all?

Comment: @user2357112 obviously I want to access them, what I wanted to say that the order of them doesn't matter, I'm not interested in any particular "snapshot" of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Array sizes in Java don't change...ever.

Iterating through an array is essentially looping through array indices and getting the element at each index -- whether you do it explicitly, or you use the shiny `for( Entity e: array ) ...` syntax -- so there's no way the iteration itself will go wrong, even with changing array contents.

The objects you're going to see through the iteration may not constitute a valid "snapshot" of the contents of the array at any given point in time, but as far as I understand, this is not an issue in your case.

Comment: It is an issue to have no synchronization of array access. Consider a scenario where all assignments to the array are in thread `A` and all the reads from the array are in thread `B`. Thread `B` might see only `null` values always no matter how many references thread `A` has stored, unless there's some sort of synchronization.

Comment: @Lew Bloch For one thing, OP has indicated that they "don't care about the objects which are "inside" the array", so any consistency point is moot.  For another, I neither fully understand your example, nor do I imagine how it could possibly be related to synchronization.

Comment: Without any _happens-before_ points between the threads, there's no guarantee of memory visibility between them. Thread `A` theoretically ​could finish its writes to any or all of the array elements and no other thread could see the written values, seeing instead only the initial state of the array. Without some form of synchronization the program cannot establish the necessary _happens-before_ barriers. Does that clarify it for you, @shinobi?

Comment: @Lew Bloch Yes it does -- now I understand your point, and it is still moot, in the context of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make array thread safe as follows:

list arryList = new ArrayList();
list arratListNew= Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);

//Here arratListNew will be threadsafe array.

Comment: ArrayList is not array.